# cant get equation solved

Tags: arithmetic

Hello I am having trouble solving this equation. I know the answer is $10.663$, but I am getting $1.146485093853515e-5$, for the top I get $29.904$ and the bottom I get $2608320$. Where do you think I am not correctly solving the equation? I must be doing something wrong I didn't think I was this bad at math. Any help is appreciated thanks

$$ \frac{(12 -0.3-3.3)\times (0.26 + 3.3)}{(12 - 0.3 + 0.26) \times 380\,000 \times 0.3 \times 2} $$

Comment: i can not see an equation

Comment: Try an edit with a preview so you can display the problem. Use the MathJax Tutorial to help write equations here.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I interpreted your two math statements as a fraction and edited your question. Does this look correct?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Dando18 yes thats correct sorry i thought i formatted it right,that looks better then the way i had it.

Comment: @Adrian Naranjo The question is are you getting the same values iam getting 29.904 and 2608320 for solving each side of the fraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up somewhere in the denominator,
\begin{align}
 &= \frac{ (8.4) \times (3.56) }{ (11.96) \times 380\,000 \times 0.6 } \\
 &= \frac{ 29.904 }{ 2\,726\,880 } \\
 &= 0.00001096637, \\
\end{align}

which is also expressible as $10.96637 \times 10^{-6}$. This can be shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B12-0.3-3.3%5D*%5B0.26%2B3.3%5D%5D+%2F+%5B%5B12-0.3%2B0.26%5D+*+380000+*+0.3+*+2%5D).

Comment: i see on the denominator the 0.3 + 0.26 i was adding first then subtracting it from 12.That was my problem thanks